# Is there any online/desktop tool to keep up with blogs?

Tags: windows-7, rss, blogging, tracking

Is there any tool that can help to keep up with 10 blogs?

I want to be able to check from one place which blog has a new post. Instead of manualy check them one be one.

**Operating System**: Windows 7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader) is an excellent online choice.

There are plenty of desktop tools available as well, ranging from integrated RSS support in Outlook/Thunderbird to separate RSS clients, such as [Liferea](http://liferea.sf.net/) for Linux.

Please mention your OS, so people can give you recommendations about desktop software.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Liferea](http://liferea.sourceforge.net/) to keep up with several dozen. Google Reader is another.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.netvibes.com/ is another alternative, it was slightly buggy so I stopped using it but the basic functionality was very good.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Google Reader** and **Liferea** have already been suggested...

**[Newsbeuter](http://newsbeuter.org/)**, the `mutt` of feed readers. *(Not for Windows, but nobody uses mutt on it either.)*

(Both Newsbeuter and Liferea can sync with Google Reader easily.)

[FeedDemon](http://www.feeddemon.com/) used to be good.